# STIntersect geography,geometry datatype

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, spatial

I have a circle and point, point intersects circle in geometry but not in geography.

```
DECLARE @circle GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(39.10591303215, 21.923140028856, 4120).STBuffer(500)
DECLARE @geogpoint GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(51.590294, 25.16387, 4120)
select @circle,@geogpoint.ToString(),@geogpoint,@circle.STIntersects(@geogpoint)


DECLARE @circle1 geometry = geometry::Point(39.10591303215, 21.923140028856, 4120).STBuffer(500)
DECLARE @geomgpoint geometry = geometry::Point(51.590294, 25.16387, 4120)
select @circle1,@geomgpoint.ToString(),@geomgpoint,@circle1.STIntersects(@geomgpoint)
```

I have lot of circle and point,problem is geometry is intersecting almost all and geography very few.

Answer (score 1):

For `Geography`, the buffer is in units per the SRID. For 4120:

```
SELECT unit_of_measure FROM sys.spatial_reference_systems WHERE spatial_reference_id = 4120
```

gives 'metre'

You are therefore adding a 500m buffer to your point. Now, what's the distance between your two (unbuffered) points?

```
DECLARE @circle GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(39.10591303215, 21.923140028856, 4120)
DECLARE @geogpoint GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(51.590294, 25.16387, 4120)
SELECT @circle.STDistance(@geogpoint)

1410017.60306578 metres
```

which explains why STIntersects returns false.

For `Geometery`, you are working in 'units'. What's the distance between your two points?

```
DECLARE @circle1 geometry = geometry::Point(39.10591303215, 21.923140028856, 4120)
DECLARE @geomgpoint geometry = geometry::Point(51.590294, 25.16387, 4120)
select  @circle1.STDistance(@geomgpoint)

12.898143234446 'units' (in this case degrees)
```

which is why your second query returns true.

Have a look at the section "Measurements in spatial data types"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx